# How do I hide an element after adding it through Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is kind of a confusing question but I am basically trying to create a workout-table where I can add sets and then hide the newly created sets. Any idea how to do this? Here is my HTML and JS code so far:

[Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN7Q3.png)

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TpNG.png)

[Table I'm Creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leMaw.png)

So as you can see the add set button works fine but once I add the set I can't hide it. I can only hide the initial set which is currently set to hidden. Here's the code outside of the picture if this helps:

```js
document.querySelector('.add-set-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var html = '<tr class="new-set"><td colspan="2"></td><td>Warm-up</td><td>120lbs</td><td>12</td><td>90s</td></tr>';
  document.querySelector('.add-html').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
});



document.querySelector('.hide-row').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('.toggle-view-btn').addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.hide-row').style.display === "none") {
      document.querySelector('.hide-row').style.display = "table-row";
    } else if (document.querySelector('.hide-row').style.display === "table-row") {
      document.querySelector('.hide-row').style.display = "none";
    }
  })
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #cbcbcb;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background-color: #202d3a;
}

.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-set {
  text-align: center;
}

.add-set-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="workout-table">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Exercise</th>
          <th>Sets</th>
          <th>Weight</th>
          <th>Reps</th>
          <th>Rest</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn-dark btn btn-sm toggle-view-btn"><i class="icon ion-md-add"></i></button></td>
          <td>Bench Press</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>120lbs</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>90s</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide-row">
          <td colspan="2"></td>
          <td>Warm-up</td>
          <td>120lbs</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>90s</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="add-html">
          <td class="add-set" colspan="6"><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm add-set-btn"><i class="icon ion-md-add"></i> Add Set</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Give all the newly added sets a class, then loop over all the elements with that and toggle their `display` styles.

Comment: So should I create an empty array or how would I loop over the new elements?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".classname").forEach(element => { code that does what you want to element });`

Comment: Post your new code in the question.

Comment: I got it now, thank you for your help I really appreciate it! If there are any other issues I will post it here